# Cannot connect via Tor

Tags: configuration, bridge

I have tried every thing and I even mailed for new bridges but nothing is getting connected.Its stuck at 10%.I have tried obfs3, obfs4 everything.I don't have access to VPN.

This is the tor log.

```
1/1/2016 20:53:55 PM.300 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
1/1/2016 20:53:55 PM.300 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
1/1/2016 20:53:55 PM.300 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
1/1/2016 20:53:55 PM.300 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
1/1/2016 20:53:55 PM.500 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 
1/1/2016 20:53:55 PM.700 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 
1/1/2016 20:54:15 PM.900 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
1/1/2016 20:54:15 PM.900 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
1/1/2016 20:54:15 PM.900 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
1/1/2016 20:54:15 PM.900 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 1; recommendation warn; host E946C3D2C0AC0E68549A2F719A30595BA6861E05 at 188.166.236.149:8443) 
1/1/2016 20:54:15 PM.900 [WARN] 1 connections have failed: 
1/1/2016 20:54:15 PM.900 [WARN]  1 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
1/1/2016 20:54:20 PM.800 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 2; recommendation warn; host 09A12F6C061847F57C5A122BF2B9797B6671EE28 at 178.54.4.48:443) 
1/1/2016 20:54:20 PM.800 [WARN] 3 connections have failed: 
1/1/2016 20:54:20 PM.800 [WARN]  2 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
1/1/2016 20:54:20 PM.800 [WARN]  1 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object)
```

Can anyone help me configure this?

Comment: please post your `torrc` config file